# Sequentially fade in divs on coming into view with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm currently using jquery.inview to detect when certain elements are fully visible in the browser. I have this working correctly like so:

```
$('.exclusive').bind('inview',function(e, isInView, visiblePartX, visiblePartY) {
    var elem = $(this);
    if (elem.data('inviewtimer')) {
        clearTimeout(elem.data('inviewtimer'));
        elem.removeData('inviewtimer');
    }
    if (isInView) {
        elem.data('inviewtimer', setTimeout(function() {
            if (visiblePartY == 'top') {
                elem.data('seenTop', true);
            } else if (visiblePartY == 'bottom') {
                elem.data('seenBottom', true);
            } else {
                elem.data('seenTop', true);
                elem.data('seenBottom', true);
            }
            if (elem.data('seenTop') && elem.data('seenBottom')) {
                elem.animate({ 'opacity' : 1}, 1000)
                elem.unbind('inview');
            }
        }, 1000))
    }
});
```

However, I want to amend this code slightly, so that when there are multiple matched elements in view, these are faded in sequentially with a slight delay between each. And of course when the user moves the viewport to bring more elements into view it will continue to do the same. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can delay fading in of particular elements like this:

```
var divs = $('div'); // replace with your selector

$.each(divs, function(i, item) {

    setTimeout(function() {
        $(item).fadeIn(1000);
    }, 1000 * i);

});​
```

Check the live [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tmmxv/).